# Get the right result from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `stops` and `arrivaletimes` how can I get the one `route` related to the stop_id if the location is found and not alle route like now.  For example if the stop `ABC` is found I want to get the route of this stop_id depend on the current time.

[image]

[image]

result the query:

```
SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops ON  
    arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id WHERE 
    time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
```

[image]

but I want to get just the route `1` as result and not all route which related to stop_id

Comment: if you want to filter based on stop name = ABC, use `name LIKE ABC` in where clause

Comment: @PratikBhat: where can I add this statement in my statement?

Comment: `SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops ON  
    arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id WHERE 
    time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
    and name LIKE 'ABC'`

Comment: @PratikBhat: but it is not always `ABC` it could be another stop  I want to get th route from the found stop and not just `ABC` it could be stop `sky`.

Comment: that was just an example, you should use parameterized query to make it work for any stop. Store the chosen stop name and add it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB corrected query with location:

```
SELECT 
    route FROM arrivaltimes 
INNER JOIN 
    stops ON arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id 
INNER JOIN 
    stops ON arrivaltimes.location = stops.location 
WHERE 
    time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i') = time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
ORDER BY 
    arrivaltimes.stop_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Let us know results.

Comment: I added it at the last and I am getting `Column 'stop_id' in order clause is ambiguous `

Comment: Updated for you...see my answer and try again

Comment: with your answer I am getting the biggest number and not the one related to the found location.

Comment: See complete query - considers location as well.

Comment: @MrPencil Check this query now and share results...hope it helps

Comment: what is emp in 'emp.location'?

Comment: I have replaced it with your table name i.e. arrivaltimes